# Prevent sbt from updating

Tags: sbt

I have a project which fails on update stage (`unresolved dependency`). I want to execute a task to debug (`sbt resolvers`), but launching sbt triggers the update stage, preventing me from going any further.

Any mean to prevent sbt from updating?

Comment: The resolvers tried to resolve the unresolved dependencies should already have been printed in the output.

Comment: @thirstycrow Yeah I know that, and precisely it seems not all resolvers are tried. That's what I wanted to investigate.